# Are extra reflection configurations needed for custom Spring Boot starter libraries when using Spring Native?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter, spring-native

I am in the process of building a set of shared libraries using custom Spring Boot starter auto configuration per guidance from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.7/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration. Great feature offered by Spring Boot by the way! My question is that how does Spring Native support these types of custom Spring Boot Starter libraries? Are extra reflection configurations or native hints required?  I have been evaluating Spring Native and I am very excited about the performance boost it brings to Spring Boot apps!  I am eagerly awaiting Spring Boot 3 GA to be released!  Any advice on how Spring Boot 3 and/or Spring Native handles custom Spring Boot starter libraries and if any extra configurations are required will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to Sébastien Deleuze, one of the members on Spring Native team, and his response to my question is as follows.  Thanks Sébastien!

"Spring Native and the upcoming Spring Boot 3 should support this kind of autoconfiguration if they follow certain guidelines, like using @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods=false).
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#how-to-contribute-design for more details.

Spring Boot 3 will likely define more clearly the guidelines."